# Collectd config attribute "TimeToLive"

Tags: collectd

According to the official collectd documentation found [here](https://collectd.org/documentation/manpages/collectd.conf.5.shtml).

> TimeToLive 1-255 Set the time-to-live of sent packets. This applies to
>   all, unicast and multicast, and IPv4 and IPv6 packets. The default is
>   to not change this value. That means that multicast packets will be
>   sent with a TTL of 1 (one) on most operating systems.

In a nutshell, can anyone explain to me what really is TimeToLive? The description they got there is not clear to me.

*"TimeToLive -> Sets the time-to-live of sent packets"*

Don't find this very helpful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a collectd concept, but merely a networking one: the maximum number of routers the packet should be allowed to traverse before being dropped.